# How can i Centralized the datas in the horizontal tableview using table cell in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, for-loop, alignment

How can i do like this in horizontal table view

I am fresher for iphone application development ,here i have using a horizontal UITableView with custom images (web images) , i want to show the images like a center position with showing a forward and backward image for the left and right side of the middle image.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add the three `UIImageView` on the `contentView` of `UITableViewCell` or subclass `UITableViewCell` and show use it in your `UITableView`.[Apple Doc UITableViewExample understanding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html).